# How to compare a string with another where the one has space in between

Tags: regex, scala, string-comparison

How do I compare these two string :

```
val a = "fit bit versa"
val b = "fitbit"
```

another example

```
val a = "go pro hero 6"
val b = "gopro"
```

another example

```
val a = "hero go pro  6"
val b = "gopro"
```

another example

```
val a = "hero 6 go pro"
val b = "gopro"
```

I want to get "true" for the above comparisons but not here:

```
val a = "vegan protein powder"
val b = "vega"
```

This should be false.

Currently I am doing:

```
def matchPattern(a:String, b: String):String=
{
      val dd = a.split(" ")
      val result = dd.map(_.toLowerCase())
      if(result contains b.toLowerCase) true 
      else false
}
```

This works for last case but not the rest.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What about `val a = "foo gopro bar"; val b = "gopro"` and `val a = "foo go pro hero bar"; val b = "goprohero`?

Comment: Yeah.. all these should return true

Comment: `\bf\s*i\s*t\s*b\s*i\s*t\b` and `\bg\s*o\s*p\s*r\s*o\b` and `\bv\s*e\s*g\s*a\b` where regexes are case insensitive.

Comment: @sln I think the OP is looking for a generic function `matchPattern`, not a some regular expressions for this particular case. It would be good if the OP explained the rules of the test more clearly.

Comment: @Tim - Obviously, the regex is generated by putting `\s*` between each character and bookending with the `\b`'s.

Comment: @sln The code for this may not be obvious to everyone, so perhaps you could share it with us? You could include a curried version of `matchPattern` that is more efficient when checking the same word in multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `sliding(i)`, where `i` ranges from 2 to word-count in `a`, to assemble a list of all possible concatenated adjacent words.  It is then checked to see whether `b` exactly matches any of the elements in the list, as shown below:

```
def matchPattern(a: String, b: String): Boolean = {
  val words = a.toLowerCase.split("\\s+")

  val concats = (2 to words.size).foldLeft(words)(
    (acc, i) => acc ++ words.sliding(i).map(_.mkString)
  )

  concats contains b.toLowerCase
}

matchPattern("Hero go Pro 6", "gopro")
// res1: Boolean = true

matchPattern("Hero go Pro 6", "gopro6")
// res2: Boolean = true

matchPattern("Vegan protein powder", "vega")
// res3: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution to your problem.

```
def matchPattern(a: String, b: String): Boolean =
  a
    .split("\\s+")
    .tails
    .flatMap(_.inits)
    .exists(_.mkString("") == b)
```

This will check for any word or sequence of words in `a` that exactly matches the word in `b`. It will reject cases where `b` is embedded in a longer word or sequence of words.

The `split` call turns the string into a list of words.

The `tails` call returns all the possible trailing sub-sequences of a list, and `inits` returns all the leading sub-sequences. Combining the two generates all possible sub-sequences of the original list.

The `exist` call joins the words together and compares them with the test word.

---

Note that `tails` and `inits` are lazy, so they will generate each solution to be tested in turn, and stop as soon as a solution is found. This is in contrast to the solutions using `sliding` which create every possible combination before checking any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `for/yield` that turned out similar to @leo-c approach. A `for` is used to generate a sliding window of length `i` from `words` to return the original words and combinations.

```
def matchPattern(a:String, b: String): Boolean =  {
  val words = a.split(" ")

  val combinations = words ++ (for(
    i <- (2 to words.size);
    acc <- words.sliding(i)
  ) yield acc).map(_.mkString)

  combinations.contains(b)
}
```

Test cases:

```
val a = "fit bit versa"
val b = "fitbit"

val c = "go pro hero 6"
val d = "gopro"

val e = "hero go pro  6"  
val f = "gopro"

//false
val g = "vegan protein powder"
val h = "vega"

val i = "foo gopro bar"
val j = "gopro"

val k = "foo go pro hero bar"
val l = "goprohero"

scala> matchPattern(a,b) && matchPattern(c,d) && matchPattern(e,f) &&  !matchPattern(g,h) && matchPattern(i,j) && matchPattern(k,l) 

res175: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this I guess (your requirements are incomplete, so I interpreted them to "match exactly the beginning portion of the given string, ending with whitespace or end of line, except maybe spaces).

```
  @tailrec
  def matchWords(input: Seq[Char], words: Seq[Char]): Boolean = (input, words) match {
     case (Seq(), Seq() | Seq(' ', _*)) => true
     case (Seq(), _) => false
     case (Seq(a, tail@_*), Seq(b, rest@_*)) if a == b => matchWords(tail, rest)
     case (_, Seq(' ', rest@_*)) => matchWords(input, rest)
     case _ => false
   }
```