# Scala substring match to match noun

Tags: regex, scala

Is there any regex to match substring if they have space in between in scala ?

For eg:

```
 "hero 6 go pro" contains "gopro" should return true
 "go pro hero 6 " contains "gopro" should return true
```

I tried :

```
   def matchWords(input: Seq[Char], words: Seq[Char]): Boolean = (input, words) match {
         case (Seq(), Seq() | Seq(' ', _*)) => true
         case (Seq(), _) => false
         case (Seq(a, tail@_*), Seq(b, rest@_*)) if a == b => matchWords(tail, rest)
         case (_, Seq(' ', rest@_*)) => matchWords(input, rest)
         case _ => false
       }
```

but

matchWords("gopro", "hero 6 go pro") returns false

though this matchWords("fitbit", "fit bit versa") return true.

The string should match nouns.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks,
Shalini

Comment: Why not use a simpler approach: remove all whitespace and use `contains`? `"hero 6 go pro".replaceAll("\\s+", "").contains("gopro")`? I see no restriction to the string pattern in the question. NOTE: regex is syntax and grammar unaware, it will match any sequence of chars meeting the pattern.

Comment: That might be giving bad results for "vegan protein shake" contains "vega" .. vegan and vega are not same.

Comment: @user3407267: then how do you define when there should be a space and when there should not be?

Comment: I am looking for more like nouns..

Comment: Then add the **whole word** restriction to the question. And your attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 0):

A user with the same "name" as you has already asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082967/how-to-compare-a-string-with-another-where-the-one-has-space-in-between/54089280#54089280) and been given multiple answers, including [one from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082967/how-to-compare-a-string-with-another-where-the-one-has-space-in-between/54089280#54089280).

The code in your question appears to be copied from another of those answers. Unfortunately you picked the lowest-scoring answer which doesn't give the right results.

I suggest that you try my answer from that question...